# How do change <li> elements that are NOT active with pure CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I understand how to change the description of an active `<li>` element

```
li:active {
...declarations...
}
```

But how can I change all the other elements **that are NOT active**?

For example, all my elements are in bold, but when I select one of them, all the others are changed back to normal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

I'd imagine `li:not(:active)` should at least theoretically work.

Comment: +1 Yes, but this is CSS3 only so Brad's answer is much more compatible.

Comment: @BoltClock: Hum. `:not` has been around for so long I actually thought it was CSS 2(.1). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You mean in jQuery? Yeah, because jQuery selectors are adapted from CSS3 :)

Comment: @BoltClock: No, I mean in CSS. Perhaps not supported by browsers, but still "around" (say, like `:hover` has been around for ages but it took years for IE to start supporting it properly)

Answer (score 8):

Apply a rule to ALL of them, then apply a different rule to the active.

```
li {
   color: blue;
}

li:active {
  color: red;
}
```

Result: the un-active ones are **blue**.

Comment: +1 A good alternative to the CSS3-only `:not()` pseudo-class. This one also makes more sense because the elements should be inactive *by default* anyway.

Comment: If I understand the example correctly this one won't work as requested.

Comment: Thanks Brad, but this won't do. In your example all the elements are in blue. What I am looking for is that they become blue once an element becomes active.

Answer (score 3):

After rereading your question, I think the real answer is that you can't use CSS alone to control how the elements behave on user interaction.

I realize that this won't work because the styles are applied **immediately**, and elements in the DOM are typically not `:active` **by default**:

```
li {
    font-weight: bold;
}

li:not(:active) {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Plus, `:not()` is a CSS3 pseudo-class, so support for it is rather poor right now if you have to account for older browsers.

Maybe you can do this with JavaScript (I use jQuery here)...

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().css('font-weight', 'normal');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The :not() pseudo class is exactly what I was looking for. Tested it on FF3, Chrome and IE8. IE8 does not support it, but that's ok.

Comment: @Roberto: Do you mean using CSS `:not()` alone does work as expected?

Comment: "I realize that this won't work because the styles are applied immediately, and elements in the DOM are typically not :active by default:" 
Yet a link is never hovered by default at the moment the stylesheet loads, but :hover works perfectly fine? Not sure if your argument is valid. I do agree on the solution tho, but maybe for another reason :P

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly this should do it,

```
li{  font-weight:bold; }

:active li{ font-weight: normal; }

:active li:active{ font-weight: bold; }
```

So basically you want an active state on the parent which switches everything to normal and then override that for the li that is also active.

Comment: Come on guys this is the answer, no?

Comment: But will the `ul` element count as active if a child `li` is active? Time to test this, good thinking indeed

Comment: Seems to be so, yes, the element you're clicking on and all of its parents have active state triggered. It's the same with a hover.

Answer (score 0):

To expand Brad's answer based on your example:

You want all `<li>`'s to be bold, until one is clicked, right? Start off with:

```
li { 
  font-weight: bold; 
}
```

Then, if a list item is clicked keep that one bold but make the others regular:

```
li:active ~ li {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

The ~ selects all elements that are siblings of the active li, without selecting the active one itself.

Comment: `~` selects siblings that only come **after** the active `li`. I see your point about what the OP expects though...

Comment: @Stephan, is the `~` CSS3 or CSS2.x?

Comment: CSS3, but supported by every browser except IE6: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#CSS3